# Restart Guessing a Number game if the user type YES

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I've created a program that generates a random number and the user try to guess it. It will inform you if you have put a higher or smaller number until you guess the correct number. After guessing the correct number, it will ask you if you want to play again. If you type `YES`, the program should restart, but if you type `NO`, it should print `Goodbye` and close.

**My program:**

```
int main() {
    int num, guess, tries = 0;
    srand(time(0)); //seed random number generator
    num = rand() % 100 + 1; // random number between 1 and 100
    cout << "Guess My Number Game\n\n";
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a guess between 1 and 100 : ";
        cin >> guess;
        tries++;
        if (guess > num)
            cout << "Too high!\n\n";
        else if (guess < num)
            cout << "Too low!\n\n";
        else
            cout << "\nCorrect! You got it in " << tries << " guesses!\n";
    } while (guess != num);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a [do while loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do) that runs while user input isn't "no". Don't forget to put your srand before the loop, and to re-initialize any other variables you might have.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `rand()` and or `srand()` I prefer to use the Pseudo Random Number Generators from the standard library that can be found in the `<random>` header file. You can take a look at my small application to see what is happening for the random generators.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

int main() {
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 gen;
    gen.seed( rd() );
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist( 1, 100 );

    int hiddenNumber = dist( gen ); 
    int guess = 0;
    int attempts = 0;
    std::string userResponse;

    do {            
        if ( attempts == 0 ) {
            std::cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 100: ";
        }
        std::cin >> guess;
        ++attempts;

        if ( guess < hiddenNumber ) {           
            std::cout << "\nYour guess was to low: Please try again!\n";
        } else if ( guess > hiddenNumber ) {
            std::cout << "\nYour guess was to high: Please try again!\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "\nYou guessed it in " << attempts << " tries!\n";
            std::cout << "\nWould you like to try again yes/no?\n\n";

            userResponse.clear(); // clear out string first.
            std::cin >> userResponse;

            if ( userResponse == "yes" || userResponse == "Yes" ) {
                attempts = 0;
                hiddenNumber = dist( gen );
                continue;
            } else if ( userResponse == "no" || userResponse == "No" ) {
                std::cout << "Goodbye!" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while ( guess != hiddenNumber );

    std::cout << "/nPress any key to quit.";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

---

This section of code here that pertains to the random numbers I will explain in some detail:

```
static std::random_device rd;
static std::mt19937 gen;
gen.seed( rd() );
static std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist( 1, 100 );
```

The 1<sup>st</sup> line is a mechanism to be able to seed a generator or an engine from the library. There are several ways you can seed a generator

- `std::random_device`
- `std::seed_seq`
- a literal constant value
- `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`

Once you have the type of mechanism to seed your generator there is a long list of generators available from the standard library but of the most commonly used is the Mersenne Twister that can be shown from the 2<sup>nd</sup> line of code declared as `std::mt19937` there is also a 64bit version of this `std::mt19937_64`. This is the engine that we are using.

The 3<sup>rd</sup> line of code is taking the seeding mechanism and applying it to our generator as in `gen.seed( rd() );`.

After we have our generator set up and ready to go, we need a way to evenly or more properly to distribute the numbers randomly so we need what is called a distribution. Again there are many kinds of distributions in the standard library but there are normally 2 distinct types of each but not always, and those two types are the integral versions and the real versions. Some distributions may only have definitions for one or the other while some may have both.

In you case or example you are generating whole numbers or integers from `[1,100]` so here I chose to use `std::uniform_int_distribution<>`. These distributions are template types. However they do have defaults as shown above. If the `uniform_int_distribution` is defaulted it will simply use int, but you can pass `unsigned int`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `char`, `unsigned char`, `bool`, etc. to the template parameter list as long as it is an integral type. If you are working with floating point types (real) it is the same such as `uniform_real_distribution<>` it will default to use a `double` but it can take a `float` or any other decimal type number.

So now that you know how the distributions are declared-defined we can go ahead and do that as you can see from the 4<sup>th</sup> line. We are using the default type for the template parameter list. Then we declare a variable namded `dist` that it accepts two parameters into is constructor (min, max). Here we want to generator numbers from `[1,100]` so we declared it as `dist(1, 100)`.

Now that we finally have all of that setup we can now use both our Distribution and already seeded generator to give us a random number. To do this we simply take our already constructed distribution and pass to it our generator and return the result back into our local variable.

```
int hiddenNumber = dist( gen );
```

It is that simple to use the modern c++ Pseudo Random Number Generators over the undesirable deprecated or soon to be deprecated `rand()` and `srand()` functions.

Now as for declaring the variables as static; I chose to make these static for performance reasons, as opposed to have them as local stack variables.

For more information on the standard libraries random generators and distributions you can visit [cppreference : random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

As for the rest of the code it should be self explanatory.

---

**EDIT** - *I made some changes to the do while loop. I went back and ran it through the debugger and it was not working as I was expecting. It is now working correctly from what I can tell. All the variables are being reset at the right place and I even added in the extra bit to say "Good Bye!".*

Comment: Your answer is informative, however, it has nothing to do with what was asked in the question.

Comment: @aaamourao Well after reading the posted question from the OP; I did not see any viable question... So I decided to give the OP some helpful tips for future references on using a better mechanism for random numbers than `rand()` or `srand()`.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Thank you, your answer was very helpful to me.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I got it, and you did it well. There is just a problem on your example: If the user guesses the correct number, and decide to play again, the hidden number will be the same than in the last round.

Comment: @aaamourao Nice catch; It would have to be reset

Comment: Yeah; I'm not to crazy about do-while loops; they kind of trip me up.

Comment: I made some necessary edits as there were a few bugs in the program.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
while (1) {
    num = rand() % 100 + 1;
    do {
        ...
    } while (guess != num);
    cout << "Restart?" << endl;
    // Get answer and break if it is NO
}
```

Comment: That's what a [do-while](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do) is for. A `break` is not necessary in this case, since you check the condition at the end of the loop.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux break here is for the external `while (1)` loop, and is used for modeling a problem just like "run it until the user asks it to break". Of course, it could be implemented with a `while-do` statement, but it is just a matter of preference.